# Synergy for Linux-Mint-20

Tags: linux-mint

I am currently trying to configure my synergy setup. All websites and installation guides just tell to use:

`sudo apt-get install synergy`

I tried that and it says "Unable to locate package synergy"

I tried downloading a .deb file for that and it said:
"dependency is not satisfiable: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3)"

though I get the same "Unable to locate package libqt4-network" message when I just try to download it through the terminal. And even when I download some other synergy versions, I am always some 'lib' away from using synergy. Specifically libcrypto++6 and libcrypto++9.

Is there a way to download synergy for linux-mint 20?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunateley, Synergy seems to [have changed to closed source](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=15335174).

Thus, Version 2.x builds are unlikely to appear in Open Source Package repos.
The old versions are built against Qt4, which is replaced by Qt5 in Linux Mint 20, thus you will not be able to install an old version, as you tried.

(I tried installing the above-mentioned package libqt4-network, but it depends on other qt4 packages and so on...)

However, it is possible to build the old synergy code using the new Qt5, [as this guy did](https://rephlex.de/blog/2020/04/24/synergy-1-11-1-package-for-ubunu-20-04-focal-fossa/).

I hope someone will create a PPA for this, soon.